# fdupes - delete files after comparing two directories

Tags: shell-script, files, rm, fdupes

I'm currently trying to solve an issue using `fdupes`. I'd like to compare two folders with each other, and afterwards delete all duplicate files within one of these directories.

Example:

Files are being stored automatically in `/srv/`—lots of duplicates there. They shall be all left untouched. I also have a dir called `/watchfolder/` and I want to remove all files in `watchfolder` if they are existent in `/srv/`.

I've tried `fdupes -r srv/ watchfolder/` and the other way around. But it keeps messing with my files in `srv/`.

Answer (score 5):

### Filter When Recursing with Fdupes

If you have more than one duplicate then you might end up with something like:

```
srv/foo                               
srv/a/b/foo
watchfolder/foo
watchfolder/c/foo
watchfolder/d/foo
```

In such a case, you need to feed the list of duplicates into a filter or shell script to apply some smarter rules, unless you only want to preserve the very first duplicate found (e.g. the least deeply-nested match in srv). If that's all you want, then:

```
fdupes --recurse --delete srv/ watchfolder/
```

would work. For more complex situations, such as wanting to preserve everything in srv/, consider a filter like:

```
fdupes --recurse srv/ watchfolder/ | sed '/^srv/d; /^$/! s/.*/"&"/' | xargs rm
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider last example as a good practice. If _watchfolder/_ contains duplicates of file which copy is not contained in _srv/_ it leads to data loss.
Be careful and make backups before that action.

Answer (score 3):

fdupes will keep the first file, as in the file with the earliest timestamp. It is a bit misleading in what it states in the help.

```
$ ll foo/ bar/
bar/:
total 12
-rw-rw-r--. 1 BriGuy BriGuy   2 Jul 23 16:10 a
-rw-rw-r--. 1 BriGuy BriGuy 102 Jul 23 16:22 b
-rw-rw-r--. 1 BriGuy BriGuy 610 Jul 23 16:23 c

foo/:
total 12
-rw-rw-r--. 1 BriGuy BriGuy   2 Jul 23 16:10 a
-rw-rw-r--. 1 BriGuy BriGuy 102 Jul 23 16:11 b
-rw-rw-r--. 1 BriGuy BriGuy 610 Jul 23 16:22 c

$ fdupes foo/ bar/
foo/b                                   
bar/b

foo/c
bar/c
# in above foo/b and foo/c would be kept

$ cp bar/c foo/c
$ fdupes foo/ bar/
bar/c                                   
foo/c

foo/b
bar/b
# in above foo/b and bar/c would be kept,
# as bar/c has an earlier timestamp than foo/c now
```

Comment: A good addendum to this (good) answer would also be the case when `bar` and `foo` get swapped: `$fdupes bar/ foo/`. Because, unlike you might think, the output is likely to be the very same as in `$fdupes foo/ bar/`, since timestamp is the only thing it cares for, as you correctly pointed out. This can drive you totally nuts if you want to keep one folder as-is no matter what. And since fdupes can only protect the first file (top-down), the order WILL be important. Anyways, I consider any method involving `grep` or `sed` an ugly workaround for a badly-conceived tool.