# how to tell fdupes which files to keep?

Tags: backup, fdupes

I have had problems with my backup and now I have many folders several times on my HD. I have one main 'folder tree', which I want to keep as is. How can I prevent fdupes from deleting files in directories I don't want it to delete?

Is there maybe another duplicate finding utility?

Comment: fdupes does a really bad work, for I watched it deleting files which definitely cannot contain the same content.
I used fdupes -rdI /home/user/path/to/dir/*

Comment: Do you mean that there are directories in your tree that you want just want fdupes to ignore?

Comment: When it comes for fdupes to delete one of two files, it keeps the oldest one. [soruce: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146200/154403]

Comment: But it will keep the oldest one of two files with the same MD5 and bitwise identicality. We are not talking 'same name, different date, maybe some changes', we are talking 'exact copy of the earlier file'.

Comment: I know, should've been clear. Actually, when I currently run it, it seems fdupes finds files with one duplicate maximum. Now, it compares each md5sum-each file couple and deletes separately. This wasn't in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there maybe another duplicate finding utility?

Use [rmlint](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it does exactly what you want using the --keep-all-tagged option:

```
$ rmlint --types=duplicates --keep-all-tagged /path/to/dupes /other/path/to/dupes // main/folder/tree
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not slow the process down and take some care

Get the comparison of duplicates from `fdupes` and put it in a file.

```
fdupes -r /path/to/start > filesToDelete
```

Then, at your own speed, you can remove any directories or files you want to keep from the `filesToDelete`

To remove entire directories

```
sed -i '|/directoryToKeep/|d' filesToDelete
```

Work through `filesToDelete` in your preferred text editor and put a marker (maybe an x?) at the beginning of the copy of each file you want to **keep** so you can keep track of what you have done, and then, when you are sure of the changes

```
cat aFile | xargs -d "\n" rm
```

`rm` will throw an error at each line with an x (as well as at any comment or other lines generated  by `fdupes`) but do nothing to those files. It will, however, delete all of the unmarked valid filename entries in `filesToDelete`.

Comment: That's the manual way, which is reasonable for few duplicates. I have some thounsands of files... Can I just change permissions for the folder I want to keep (e.g. `chown -R root /home/user/path/to/keep && chmod -R -037 /home/user/path/to/keep`)?

Comment: Could I just tell fdupes to move the files (with their folder hierarchy) to a specified folder? I could delete then the files manually, but all specific at once.

Comment: You can do whatever you like. At the end of the day someone (that's you) has to describe in terms the system understands exactly what criteria to use in deciding which files to delete. If you cannot formulate these in your own mind then there is a danger of mistaken deletion. I only really made the bost because of

Comment: You can do whatever you like, but at the end of the day someone (that's you) has to describe in terms the system understands exactly what criteria to use in deciding which files to delete. If you cannot formulate these in your own mind then there is a danger of mistaken deletion. I can't see a better way of finding duplicates than comparing MD5 and then bitwise comparison. In your shoes I would get the output to file, do a random check of files that fdupes calls 'duplicate' and if I was happy then just let it do its job ... after moving any 'critical' files out of the search path

Comment: This is really just a matter of using the tools you have at hand, like sort and a text editor. I was in a similar situation, that's what brought me here =). After bu5hman's suggestion, do 'sort filesToDelete SortedFiles2Delete'. There you have a list of duplicates according to hierarchy! It should be easy to delete the lines from SortedFiles2Delete, and do a while read DELETEFILE ; do mv "${DELETEFILE}" trashcan/. ; done < SortedFiles2Delete ... you get the idea. Trashcan might contain duplicates that were not at all in the part of hierarchy you want to preserve.

Comment: @WildPenguin Agree 100%. Learn the command line and "roll your own" tools. Geeks 'R' Us.....?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short script to prioritize the first directiory given. It doesn't directly delete files, only prints a list for you to delete. It follows these rules:

1. Don't print any files from `dir1`
2. If any file is not in `dir1`, then don't print it.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   # priority_dup.sh dir1 dir2 [dir3 ...]`

   set1=() # List collects all matching files for a set.
   IFS=$'\n'
   fdupes -r "$@" | while read i; do
       if [[ "$i" == "" ]]; then
           # Create new set, minus all files from dir1.
           set2="$(echo "${set1[*]}" | grep -v "^$1/")"
           # If the sets are different, then we can print files for deletion.
           if [[ "${set1[*]}" != "$set2" && "$set2" != "" ]]; then
               echo "$set2"
               echo ""
               set1=()
           fi
       else
           set1+=("$i")
       fi
   done
   ```

   Save it to a file, set the file as executable, and run try it.